# How to get multiple lists using single linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables one is `Datacenter` and `Subnet`

`Datacenter` has a primary key and `Subnet` has foreign key values of `DatacenterId`.

I need the result like, different lists for each `DatacenterId` from `Subnet` table.

```
Id DatacenterId   name      

1       1         kishore    

2       1          ..       

3       1          ..       

4       2          ..        

5       2          ..        

6       2          ..
```

I need to get two list one with `DatacenterId = 1` another with `DatacenterId = 2`

My current query is not quite working as I'd hope and I'm not sure how to correct it.

```
var myList = from o in db.EWB_SiteSubNet 
             where edbCenterIdList.Contains(o.DataCenterID) 
             select o;
```

When the query runs, `myList` contains a single list of 20 records.  What I need is 2 lists one for each of the unique `DatacenterId` values in the table.  So, for example, if my `Subnet` table has 4 unique `DatacenterId` values, the query output would need to be 4 separate lists.

Comment: You really need to make more of an effort yourself as the community generally doesn't respond well to "write this code for me" questions.  First, give us an idea what you have tried on your own.  Show us your attempt(s) and how they aren't working.  And next, give us a better idea what you want in the output.  It is not immediately clear to me what info you actually want in the output list.

Comment: I am using this code snippet,  
var myList = from o in db.EWB_SiteSubNet where edbCenterIdList.Contains(o.DataCenterID) select o;

This is giving me result of 20 records behalf of DatacenterID=1 is having 10 records and DatacenterId=2 is having 10 records, I need to  get seperate lists for every DatacenterID.
If I have 4 DatacenterID I need to get 4 lists

Comment: Just edit your code into the question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 can you help me to build the query please?..
Thanks in adv..

Comment: What version of LINQ are you using?  It is obviously not `LINQ-to-objects`, but is it `LINQ-to-Entities` or `LINQ-to-SQL`?

Comment: It is LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It is LINQ-to-Entities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never get multiple collections from a single query.  That is just a basic rule of all flavors of LINQ (Objects, SQL, and Entities).  The return value will always be a variation on `IEnumerable<T>` depending on the query and the flavor of LINQ.

However, in the query you can group the objects and return a collection of collections, so that is the approach we need to take here.

So your original query works:

```
var myList = from o in db.EWB_SiteSubNet 
             where edbCenterIdList.Contains(o.DataCenterID) 
             select o;
```

but it only gets you only halfway there, because you are just returning all records from `SubNet` that match an existing `DataCenterID`.

Since you want the records grouped by `DataCenterID`, you need to do a [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx)

```
var myList = from o in db.EWB_SiteSubNet 
             where edbCenterIdList.Contains(o.DataCenterID) 
             group o by o.DatacenterId into g
             select g.Select(r => r.ToList());
```

Now `myList` is going to be a collection of lists (`IEnumerable<List<T>>` in this case) and you can iterate over `myList` to get the individual Lists within it.  Or you can get a little fancier in the query and create a dictionary (by using [`ToDictionary()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) on `myList` so you can access the individual collections by a key value (such as the DataCenterID).